# Solr Sort By GEO Bucket

Tags: solr

In Solr, I need to boost by geo distance bucket
i.e if distance is between 0,25km give 100 score else 0.

I am trying to figure out but not able to comeup with answer.

Tried something like below but of no use. I am thinking if expression =0 , do some boost but query is not forming

> mod(abs(sub(25,geodist())),25)